# How can I remove rows where their timestamp older than now?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Basically, I fill a row with a timestamp => '1558180800' for exemple.
I want to remove all rows which their timestamp is greater than now, current timestamp.

I tried several things but didn't work :/

One example of the query I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > NOW()
```

Comment: Could you share what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, could you also show your `roompasswords` table structure as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example given, `timestamp` value of '1558180800' is `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` format. `NOW()` returns 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'. So if to directly translate your query:

```
DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > NOW();
is equivalent to
DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > '2019-05-14 09:18:06';
```

So it won't work given that it can't find that particular field value. Therefore, you need to change `NOW()` into `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`. Below are example you can try:

```
1) DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

Note that NOW() returns current date + time so if you want to specify a time as well you can do the following instead:

```
2) DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-14 00:00:00');
```

OR you can fetch the UNIX_TIMESTAMP value first then use that for your DELETE query:

```
  SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-14 00:00:00'); -- will return '1557763200'
  -- then
  DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE timestamp > '1557763200';
```

Lastly, this query will work as well:

```
 3) DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) > '2019-05-14 00:00:00';
    or
    DELETE FROM roompasswords WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) > NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` `FROM` TABLE_NAME `WHERE` timestamp_field `>` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Comment: it says incorrect datetime value, my timestamp column is varchar ? maybe I should alter it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE str_to_date(YOUR_FIELD, '%d/%m/%Y') > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Just change the format of the str_to_date accordingly.

Also have a look at this article: https://www.quora.com/I-have-a-date-column-in-varchar-format-How-can-i-change-it-to-date-format-in-mysql-workbench

So what you will be doing here is to cast you varchar column to date, then you don't have to alter your table. But best practice is to have a DateTime column for date values.